# crystal report and sql commands

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

[image]

I have a problem in showing data content from joined table in crystal report my sql query is good and it shown my own data but i when fill crystal report datasource and show it the crystal repeat duplicate and more data my code is:

```
 Dim rep As CrystalReport1 = New CrystalReport1()
Dim objcon = New SqlConnection("data source=(local);initial catalog=hesabres;user id='sa';password='Maysam7026'")
Dim objcom = New SqlCommand
Dim objdata As New DataTable
Dim objdr As SqlDataReader
objcom.CommandText = " SELECT customer.customer_name, customer.customer_tel, orders.order_stuff_name, orders.order_number" & _ " FROM   hesabres.dbo.orders orders inner JOIN hesabres.dbo.customer customer ON orders.order_customer_id=customer.customer_id"


objcom.Connection = objcon
objcon.Open()
objdr = objcom.ExecuteReader
objdata.Load(objdr)
rep.SetDataSource(objdata)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep
```

in fact may bought one chair and ball and jahan bought one ball!

Comment: What happens when you run your sql statement in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports does not show any data itself.

If your database query result is fine then their is something with their code.

I will suggest that please review your code in detail.

Apply distinct keyword in select statement as below and then check it

```
    SELECT Distinct customer.customer_name, customer.customer_tel, 
orders.order_stuff_name, orders.order_number" & _ " 
FROM   hesabres.dbo.orders orders 
inner JOIN hesabres.dbo.customer customer 
ON orders.order_customer_id=customer.customer_id
```

Comment: What Asif said. :)  Inner joins are almost always the cause of this, you want to look at your data first and see if the reason it joined multiple times was because you had multiple records in one of the two tables you're dealing with.  Like Asif said, run the query straight against the database and see if you get the same results.  If you do, you need to alter the query (either add distinct or fix the bad data if it got duplicated somehow).

Comment: thank you asif but it's n't work for more information i have 2 table(customer and orders) in customer table i save customer information such as cu_id ,cu_name ,... in customer table cu_id is p_key and in orders table i save order information of customers in orders table cu_id is f_key and relational is between p_key to f_key now i add in cr report two field from customer and to field from orders. in cr report view it's work properly but i when write sql code in vb.net add fill it to datatable and attach to cr datasource the result is diferent to datatable content!!